# How to update JLabel with ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlabel, repaint

I write an `ActionListener` of a button so that whenever you click the button, an `ArrayList<JLabel>` named `wordLabel` is clear and update with a new `ArrayList`. Unfortunately, the old `ArrayList` isn't cleared properly and it stack up with the new one

For example, before click: `SPRING`; after click: `SPRING-----` (instead of `-----`)

My code:

```
private class StartListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        startPanel.wordLabel.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++) {
            startPanel.wordLabel.add(new JLabel("_"));
            startPanel.add(startPanel.wordLabel.get(i));
        }
        startPanel.revalidate();
        startPanel.repaint();

    }
}
```

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try startPanel.wordLabel.repaint()

Comment: Why add new JLabels? Why not change the text of the previous? Creating new labels == creating new objects == overhead. What's the purpose of this anyways? And it could be a concurrent issue. Keep in mind `actionPerformed` is handled on a specific thread (the EDT). If a variable isn't declared `volatile`, a copy of the variable will be made in the Thread Local Storage specific for that thread (depending on your jvm). Either way, it seems as if you aren't showing enough code, because that looks alright to me. (clearing list then adding onto it; it shouldnt stack up)

Comment: @VinceEmigh I have checked, the `ArrayList` it self is cleared, but it continues to display the old one on the frame

Comment: @VinceEmigh and I want to create new labels because each time the button is pressed, the `wordLabel` changes in length and value, basically its a new word

Answer (score 0):

You don't clear startPanel so it has all the old JLabels and the new characters too. You can do that by adding this:

```
startPanel.removeAll();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the array is cleared, but the new array only replaces the old one's position, the text of the old one is still in the frame. Like this:

before click `SPRING`, after click `SPRING`, but when I print the text after click, it is `-----`

Answer (score 0):

If all you are wanting to do is clear your ArrayList you need to do:

```
arrayListName.clear();
```

Comment: I did it in the code above, but the old `ArrayList` is still in the frame